# Cross-platform binary in C++

Tags: c++, binary, cross-platform

I have read that a binary is the same for Windows and Linux (I am not sure if it has a different format).

What are the differences between binaries for Linux and binaries for Windows (when speaking about format)?

And if there are none, what stops us from making a single binary for both operating systems (make sure that I mean the last file where you can run and not the source code)?

Since there are differences in the binary format, how are the operating systems themselves compiled?

If I'm not mistaken Microsoft uses Windows to compile the next Windows version/update.

How are these binaries executable by the machine (even the kernel is one of those)?

Aren't they in the same format? (For such a low-level program.)

Comment: Binaries for the two operating systems are not the same unless they were built for .NET.

Comment: No binaries do not port between OSes. Windows has PE : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable, Linux has ELF : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format.

If you stick to C++ standard + STL then you can compile the same source to both platforms.

Comment: I added an edit to ask 1 more question

Comment: You can make a cross platform executable https://github.com/jart/cosmopolitan

Comment: O/S kernels are not in the same format. Not even text files are in the same format between Windows and Linux.

Comment: @AlanBirtles it is physically impossible to run the same executable file on different platforms. I'm guessing that project is using platform-specific stubs to run platform-agnostic code. But that is still not a true cross-platform executable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau nothings imposible, that project does indeed create executables that will run on multiple x86 operating systems. E.g. https://www.theregister.com/2022/06/20/redbean_2_a_singlefile_web/

Comment: If you want to now a bit more about what a Compiler/Linker/OS does to get an executable to run watch this video from Mat Godbolt (the guy from compiler explorer) : [The bits between the bits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOfucXtyEsU). There is more to it then you think

Comment: The main problem is that Windows expects a file in a different format (PE) and Linux expects one in a different format (ELF). PE files have to start with the letters "MZ" and ELF files have to start with the letters "ELF". Obviously it can't be both at once.

Comment: Very basic conceptual questions like this should not be answered. They have already been asked ***many times over***. The time is much better spend finding the canonical questions (with much better and more comprehensive answers).

Comment: @user253751 Windows can definitely run a few other formats besides PE, and I assume Linux can as well. Presumably, Cosmopolitan found formats for both that aren't in direct conflict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have read that a binary is the same for Windows and Linux (not sure if it has a different format)

Then you have read wrong.  They are completely different formats.

> What are the differences between binaries for Linux and binaries for Windows (when speaking about format)?

Windows: [Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) (PE)

Linux: *[Executable and Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)* (ELF)

> And if there are none

There are many differences.

> What stops us from making a single binary for both operating systems?

The fact that different OSes require different binary formats for their respective executable files.

> Since there are differences in the binary format, how are the operating systems themselves compiled?

Ask the OS manufacturers for details.  But basically, they are compiled like any other program (just very complex programs).  Like any other program, their source code is compiled into appropriately-formatted executable files for each platform they are targeting, and even for each target CPU.  For instance, Windows uses the PE format for all of its executables, but the underlying machine code inside each executable is different whether the executable is running on an x86 CPU vs an x64 CPU vs an ARM CPU.

> If I'm not mistaken Microsoft uses Windows to compile the next Windows version/update

Yes. That is commonly known as ["dog-fooding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) or ["bootstrapping"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)).  For instance, [VC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) running on Windows is used to develop new versions of VC++, Windows, etc.

> How are these binaries executable by the machine (even the kernel is one of those)?

When an executable file is run (by the user, by a program, etc.), a request goes to the OS, and the OS's executable loader then parses the file's format as needed to locate the file's machine code, and then runs that code on the target CPU(s) as needed.

As for running the user's OS itself, there is an even more fundamental OS running on the machine (i.e., the BIOS) which (amongst other things) loads the user's OS at machine startup and starts it running on the available CPU(s).  See [Booting an Operating System](https://people.cs.rutgers.edu/%7Epxk/416/notes/02-boot.html) for more details about that.

> Aren't they in the same format? (For such a low-level program.)

No.

Comment: A better word for "dog-fooding" is bootstrapping (in the compiler sense)

Comment: Thanks for all the info, but still I don't understand one thing, on 1 question before the last I'm asking how is the OS executable runnable by the bare metal, since there is no OS to run the OS (isn't that right?)

Comment: @user18812922 There *is* an OS underneath the OS - the computer's BIOS. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments by @AlanBirtles, this is in fact possible. See [Actually Portable Executable](https://justine.lol/ape.html), [Redbean](https://redbean.dev/2.0.html), and [the article](https://www.theregister.com/2022/06/20/redbean_2_a_singlefile_web/) about the two.

Even though the binary formats are different, it's possible to come up with a file that's valid in several different formats.

But, this being an obscure hack, I would stay away from it in production (or at all).

Comment: This Answer is helpful too, but @Remy Lebeau's answers every bit of my question, Though It's good to have this answer here too